# Meaning of "I walked slam-bang into this character"

Tags: sentence-meaning

It's a sentence as an example under [the entry "slam-bang" in Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slam-bang?q=slam-bang).

> slam-bang: suddenly and forcefully or violently
>
> I walked slam-bang into this character.

What does it mean?

Does the speaker really bump against somebody?

Comment: This is indeed worth throwing for a bounty. Can anyone let StoneyB know this? His comment is required.

Comment: @snailplane The reason is, I'm not totally convinced with the word *character* used here. Whilst Oxford is known to make things simple, why does it use that *heavy* word in the example that could be otherwise described in a way without any perplexity as here - http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SLAMBANG. See that, it's clear in all its examples.

Comment: @MaulikV Oxford uses real world examples instead of invented ones.

Comment: It sounds like "walked slap bang into" which you might get more results for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself eventually found a may-be original resouce form which the sample sentence is selected. It's from a novel *[The Enemy](http://www.rulit.net/books/the-enemy-read-174766-27.html)*:

> He had a raw colonial accent. 'We don't move out of the UK much,' I said. 'Most of our work is counterespionage. This one is a bit different. If you can take me to George Ashton I'll buy you a case of Foster's.' Henty blinked. 'Good beer, that. How did you know I'm Australian? I've not been back for twenty years. Must have lost the accent by now.' I grinned. 'Yes, you've learned to speak English very well. Where's Ashton?' He went to the window and pointed at the Royal Palace. 'On the other side of that. In Gamla Stan.' Gamla Stan-the Old Town. A warren of narrow streets threading between ancient buildings and the 'in' place to live in Stockholm. Cabinet ministers live there, and film directors-if they can afford it. The Royal Palace is No. 1, Gamla Stan. I said, 'How did you find him?' 'I got a couple of crummy pictures from London, ***and the day I got them I walked slam-bang into this character on the Vasabron***.' Henty shrugged. 'So it's a coincidence.' 'By the laws of statistics we've got to get lucky some time,' I observed. 'He has a flat just off Vasterlanggatan. He's passing himself off as a Russian called Fyodr Koslov-which is a mistake.' 'Why?' Henty frowned. 'It's a tip-off-enough to make me take the pictures and send them back. There's something funny about the way he speaks Russian-doesn't sound natural.' I thought about that. After thirty years of non-use Ashton's Russian would be rusty; it's been known for men to forget completely their native language.

From the context, I call tell the writer is saying "coincidentally met a certain person". At least in this example, it somewhat means that the writer "ran across a certain person" or more wildly speaking, "he bumped against the man in a sudden".

Comment: I am not quite sure about my answer, honestly.

Comment: It seems like you've got the right idea.

Comment: @dennylv *I got a couple of crummy pictures from London*...there, walking slam-bang into that character seems okay. Again, it's getting into someone character I think.

Comment: @MaulikV That is not correct.

Comment: @snailplane then enlighten me. what's the context there for getting crummy pictures there?

Comment: @MaulikV Henty is describing how he found Ashton, a man they'd been trying to locate.  Henty had been given a couple of photos of Ashton, and the same day he received them, they ran into each other by chance.

Comment: +1 'Bumped' is exactly right - "Guess who I just bumped into" doesn't mean "Guess who I collided with" but "Guess who I just met unexpectedly". And "slam-bang" expresses not physical violence but suddenness and surprise - "I walked around the corner and Wham! there he was!".

Answer (score 2):

The speaker really bumped against somebody.

There are a few quirks to this sentence. First, "character" is used to refer to an actual human standing in the way of the speaker. "Character" has many definitions (as you can see [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/character)), but the ones that I find relevant are:

> - a person, esp. with reference to behavior or personality: a suspicious character.
> - an odd, eccentric, or unusual person.

I believe the speaker uses "character" instead of "person" to express judgement on the person. They are suspicious or shady or just plain odd. It's also a way to keep the sentence all in the same tone. "Slam-bang" is something you would expect a 1920's gangster to say, and so is referring to a person as "character". "Get a load of this character, boss!"

... but maybe that's just me.

Anyway: Now that the confusion that in this case "character" really just means "person" is cleared up, it's also clear that "slam-bang" is an adverb modifying "walked". You could translate the whole sentence as "I walked suddenly and forcefully into this person."

Comment: No downvote but I strongly believe that when someone *walks into some character,* it means that someone *becomes* that someone as described here - http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-andhrapradesh/this-rocket-singh-rocks/article115828.ece where a person walks into the character of a salesman (he stars behaving/acting/thinking like a salesman).

Comment: Also, from the Joker (Batman) - *Whereas Ledger reinvented the Joker to suit his style of acting, Nicholson just **walked into the character** from the comics and it was a perfect fit.*

Comment: @Maulik That's another use of the phrase, though I think it would be less common to use it with "slam-bang". We would need more context to know for sure.